# How do I prevent a column being replicated in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, replication, t-sql

I'm on MSSQL 2016 using push-based transactional replication to an Azure instance. I have a few columns in our modeled data that I really do not want to replicate.

Is there a way to flag a column as "do not replicate" or something when defining a table? Or - is there a way to encrypt it such that it cannot be decrypted on a remote server? I know that you can not check the column when setting up the replication, but that feel prone to error and I'd like to have a second line of defense to avoid inadvertent replication.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the documentation for define a column filter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/define-and-modify-a-column-filter?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I'm concerned that when dropping/recreating subscriptions, it's easy to forget to exclude a column this way. I'm hoping to figure out a way to ensure that even if someone just checks the table and doesn't filter out any columns, the sensitive columns won't be replicated. Per my original question - I know you can not check the column, but I'd like an extra layer of security.

Comment: Thanks for the reply though, I appreciate you taking the time to do so :)

Comment: Encrypt the column ?

Comment: Or define a view and grant access to that & put a deny on the base table

Comment: Thanks, currently looking at encryption options. I've tried the view option, but I believe the underlying table has to be replicated as well.